# Import multiple text files to database table cells using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, import

I'm trying to transfer the contents of multiple text files into a MySQL. These files are sequentially named `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt` ... `13381.txt`. Basically, each file is an HTML document without all the headers, meta, etc. that's been stripped away and only the content is left.

I've also made an table with a columns `ID` and `CONTENT`. `ID` is auto-incrementing. I'd like the contents of the files to go into the `CONTENT` column's cells like this:

```
1.txt -> row 1
2.txt -> row 2
3.txt -> row 3
etc.
```

Searching around only leads me to importing data from CSVs and other tabular forms of data. I could always just open each file and copy-paste from there into something like phpmyadmin but that seems like a tedious thing to do given that there's thousands of data files to go through.

I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this using PHP and some kind of recursive loop that gets file contents and then UPDATEs the database. I've experimented a bit but I've seem to come against a wall beyond my mediocre programming skills. Anyone care to help? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this using PDO...

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost'; $db = 'database-name'; $user = 'database-user-name'; $pw = 'database-password';
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db.';charset=utf8', $user, $pw);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$i = 0;
do {
    $i = $i+1;
    $txt = file_get_contents("$i.txt");

try {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (CONTENT) VALUES (:txt)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':txt', $txt, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Could not complete the insert for ".$i.".txt " . $e->getMessage()); // this will tell you which of your text files caused the error
}

} while ($i <= 13381); // close for loop

echo('All Done!');
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! I tried this out and get the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object" on the line `$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);`. Did I forget to replace something? Thanks

Comment: Probably your connection file or database connection code. This should be placed above your insert code. See my edited answer

Comment: Got it, thanks! It'll probably take a while to finish but are there any pitfalls to this method? Like memory usage or execution time limits?

Additionally, I didn't even know you could connect to SQL using your method. I just normally used `mysql_connect()`.

Comment: mysql_connect() has been deprecated as of PHP version 5.5 and will be totally removed in version 7. It's best to use PDO. More information can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    try {
        $instance = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=nameofdatabase;charset=utf8", $user, $pass, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
        $instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);


    $stmt = $instance->prepare('INSERT INTO tablename SET CONTENT=:con');

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 13381; $i++)
    {
    $con = file_get_contents("/path/to/files_dir/$i.txt");
    $stmt->bindValue(':con', $con, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    }
}
    catch(PDOException $ecx) {}
```

OR 
you can use `mysql` `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement in `php` loop

Comment: Why are you recommending the use of deprecated code? [mysql has been deprecated since PHPv5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php)